# Vaadin 7 shortcut listener

Tags: java, vaadin, keyboard-shortcuts, vaadin7

Is there any way to limit the scope of shortcut listeners in vaadin 7.
I have added a shortcut listener for enter key for a component. Due to this enter key action not works in other tabs also. I want to limit the added listener to its scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the scope of shortcut key is not facilitated in vaadin 7. Only thing we can do in a scenario like this is to add and remove attached shortcut key to the component by attaching a listener to listen tab change event.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this add-on: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/keyactions - it allows you to stop the propagation of key events.

Answer (score -1):

Keyboard shortcut listeners in Vaadin 7 are active within the scope of the closest parent component that implements `Panel` or `Window`.

Comment: By adding my component inside a panel is it possible to get normal enter key behavior in other components